# How to use response files with Embarcadero Make.exe

Tags: c++builder, command-line-tool

I'm building a project via the commandline tools of C++Builder XE5, but there are too many object files so the output is:

```
MAKE Version 5.4  Copyright (c) 1987, 2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
    ilink64 ...........

Fatal: Command arguments too long
```

How do I get around this problem?

(Meta note: I'm about to answer my own question, but it took me ages to figure this out as the official documentation was not very illuminating so I am posting this Q-A in case it helps anyone else with the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

Example syntax for creating and using a response file in the makefile:

```
myproject.dll: $(MANYOBJECTS)
    ilink64 $(LINKER_FLAGS) @&&.
$(MANYOBJECTS), myproject.dll, , import64 cw64mt
.
```

The key ideas are:

- the character immediately following the `&&` is the character to be used as delimiter, other delimiters besides `.` are possible
- the text between the two `.`'s is expanded and placed in a temporary file
- The closing delimiter must be the first character on its line
- the temporary filename takes the place of the `&&.`...`.`
- Anything after the opening delimiter on the same line is ignored
- The `@` means that `ilink64` will treat the contents of the temporary file as a response file, as opposed to treating it as an object file
- Anything after the response file is actually ignored by `ilink64` despite correctly appearing in the command output (don't know why; but this means you have to make the response file contain the entire remainder of the command).

The command generated by this example was:

```
MAKE Version 5.4  Copyright (c) 1987, 2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
    ilink64 -q -aa -Tpd -x -Gn c0x64 @MAKE0000.@@@
```

(note: my linker flags may be incorrect, this is just a demonstration of how the response file works).